# Dynamically filling image alt tags with the page title, PHP

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know if it is possible to dynamically fill image alt text with the current page title?

I'm using PHP and the site is http://www.toricks.com there are thousands of pictures so going through each one isn't really an option!

Thanks

Ricky

Comment: Is that really appropriate alt text? And I would imagine that you can do it with javascript easily enough if you want but if on the serverside with php then either all your image creation calls have to go through a given function that you can edit or you'll have to capture the output stream in some way and parse it and add in the alt tag. I think you are better off not doing it though personally. :)

Comment: Sure it's possible. You'll have to provide some more detail for a concrete answer though.

Comment: How are the thousands of pictures added to the site?  If by users, then you could provide a place for them to add alt-tag information.  Where are the images coming from?  A database?  Add a field to the database for ALT text, populate as you see fit, then use that when you add the image link to the page.

Comment: to do it in php you would need a variable and you could use that both in the page title tag and any alt texts that you wanted. If you don't want to do it this way since you don't want to change every image then you would need to use some JavaScript or a JS Framework such as jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you generate the page title via a PHP value from a database and then use that same variable for your alt tag.

I built something similar to what your describing here...

http://daroom.info/index.php?rand=6260

Picture gallery with 1000s of entries notice the page title is the same as the image title on every picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it using jQuery!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').attr('alt', $("title").text());
});
```

Hope this helps! :)